# Angular 6.0.3 does not work in docker because it can not find module @angular-devkit/build-angular

Tags: angular, docker, angular6

I tried to add my angular6 app in a `docker-compose` environment. I created the project locally and it works, but after `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, it send next error:

```
angular6@0.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check -p 3000

Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/usr/src/app".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "/usr/src/app".
    at Object.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/node/resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/src/architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable.subscribe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:162:69)
    at DoOperator.call (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/tap.js:71:23)
    at Observable.subscribe (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.js:159:22)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeTo.js:22:31
    at Object.subscribeToResult (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToResult.js:7:45)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._innerSub (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:132:38)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:129:14)
    at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:112:18)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! angular6@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check -p 3000`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the angular6@0.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
angular-ayaresa    |
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-23T10_03_17_591Z-debug.log
```

This is my Angular Dockerfile :

```
# Create image based on the official Node 8.10.0 image from dockerhub
FROM node:8.10.0
# Create a directory where our app will be placed
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

# Change directory so that our commands run inside this new directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Copy dependency definitions
COPY ./quickstart /usr/src/app

# Install dependecies
RUN rm -rf node_modules/

RUN npm i --save

RUN npm i npm@latest -g
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

# Expose the port the app runs in
EXPOSE 4200

# Serve the app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

The module `@angular-devkit/build-angular` was correctly installed and included in `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your docker file
you did a **WORKDIR** and set it to ***/usr/src/app***

This means that, context will be switched to that file.

So when you do `COPY ./quickstart /usr/src/app`, this should be `COPY ./quickstart .`

The docker documentation says

`The <src> path must be inside the context of the build; you cannot COPY ../something /something, because the first step of a docker build is to send the context directory (and subdirectories) to the docker daemon.`

ref: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

I have removed a line in my docker-compose.yml.

```
angular-ayaresa:
    build:
      context: build/angular
    ports:
          - "4200:4200"
    volumes:
      - ../source/angular:/usr/src/app/
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules/ // <-- this line
    container_name: angular-ayaresa
    networks:
      - ayaresa-network
```

This line allow container to ignore a folder in volume.

The problem was that the `node_modules` was included in volumes and `Angular` searched module `"@angular-devkit/build-angular"` from local `node_modules` and not in it container `node_modules`.

I just add ignore node_modules and problem was solved.